# Can Grunt Lodash Templates Be Used In Gruntfile.js tasks?

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, lodash

Is there a way to use grunt lodash templating in gruntfile.js tasks so I can use functions like .toLowerCase().  The below snippet doesn't work, maybe it doesn't work this way since I can't find an example that fits this use case.

```
copy: {                                                                             
    plugins: {
        files: [{                       
            src: ['<%= root %>/<%= dirs.plugins %>/<%= pkg.name.toLowerCase() %>'],
            dest: '<%= root %>/<%= dirs.www %>/wp-content/plugins/<%= pkg.name %>',                                                     
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the evaluate delimiter `<%` plus the `String()` constructor to use `toLowerCase`:

```
src: ['<% String(pkg.name).toLowerCase() %>']
```

Use `npm install` to use lodash:

```
npm install lodash --save-dev
```

Then add the `require` statement to your Gruntfile.js:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var newArr = _.map(arr, fn);
```

> By default, the template delimiters used by lodash are like those in embedded Ruby (ERB). Change the following template settings to use alternative delimiters.

```
_.templateSettings = 
  {
  evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
  interpolate : /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
  escape      : /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g
  };
```

**References**

- [Grunt 0.4.2 released](http://gruntjs.com/blog/2013-11-21-grunt-0.4.2-released)
- [ECMAScript: String.prototype.toLowerCase method](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5.html#sec-15.5.4.16)
- [By default, Underscore uses ERB-style template delimiters](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/blob/master/defs/underscore.json#L447)