# XML file preprocessing during grunt build

Tags: xml, algorithm, gruntjs, environment-variables, preprocessor

We must use a corporate JavaScript library which requires a configuration.xml file. We need to support multiple configuration files, one for each environment. We have multiple files and execute a file move/rename process during our grunt build to select and rename the correct one. We would like to avoid using multiple files.

For HTML we use [grunt-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml):

```
<!-- build:js app.min.js -->
<script src="my/lib/path/lib.js"></script>
<script src="my/deep/development/path/script.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->

<!-- changed to -->
<script src="app.min.js"></script>
```

We only execute processing for release mode, so developers would work with the top block only and release would have the bottom block only.

Templating doesn't seem like a good approach as we need more than just variable replacement.

[This article](http://codebetter.com/derikwhittaker/2014/03/25/using-grunt-to-update-wmappmanifest-xml-version-number-windows-phone-manifest/) illustrates one way how to do it, but the XML modifications would reside in code which I do not want. I thought of combining that approach with an XML merge library, but before I do I would like to know how others handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Templating would work if the code resides in the Gruntfile itself. For example:

```
function dynIncludes(env)
  {
  // Script 
  var appjs = '<script src="foo.js"></script>\n';

  // Minified script
  var appminjs = '<script src="foo.min.js"></script>\n';

  if(env !== "release")
    return appjs;
  else
    return appminjs;
  }


 copy:
   {
   dev:
    {
    options: {
             process: function (content, srcpath, destpath) 
               {
               // Append script to each file in the src array
               return content + "\n" + grunt.template.process(dynIncludes('dev') );
               }
             }
    },
   release:
    {
    options: {
             process: function (content, srcpath, destpath) 
               {
               return content + "\n" + grunt.template.process(dynIncludes('release') );
               } 
             }
    }
  }
```

This uses the `process` option of the copy task:

> The source file contents, source file path, and destination file path are passed into this function, whose return value will be used as the destination file's contents. If this function returns `false`, the file
>   copy will be aborted.

This can be combined with `grunt.util.callbackify` for postprocessing:

> If the original function returns a value, that value will now be passed to the callback, which is specified as the last argument, after all other predefined arguments. If the original function passed a value to a callback, it will continue to do so.

Use [loDash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564053/1113772) to simplify the templating for more complex scenarios.

**References**

- [Grunt API: grunt.file.copy](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.copy)
- [Grunt API: grunt.util.callbackify](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.callbackify)